# Dynamic Form Input Value not updating Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, forms, object, key-value-store

new coder here. I've spent a week trying to get this to work and really need help.  I have a form with one input field.  I can query it and get the new name values.

Problem is when I use the same query in a object literal key/value pair , it doesnt show the updated values when you change the values. It only shows the original values when I console.log.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<form id="nameForm" class="nameForm" action="#">

<label id="nameLabel" for="nameInput">Enter Your Name:</label>

<input type="text" id="nameInput" class="nameInput" required>

<button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
let salonOwner = {

name: document.querySelector(#nameInput).value

}
```

Comment: Try changing it to `name: document.querySelector(".nameInput").value`

Comment: document.querySelector('#nameInput').value would also work

Comment: Thanks for fixing my syntax Dominik and osekmedia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need for your button an onclick-event, which calls your new function update. So everytime it is pressed your object will be updated.

```
<form id="nameForm" class="nameForm" action="#">
    <label id="nameLabel" for="nameInput">Enter Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" class="nameInput" required>
    <button id="next" type="button" onclick="update();">Next</button>
</form>

<script>
    function update() {
        let salonOwner = {
            name: document.querySelector("#nameInput").value
        }
        console.log(salonOwner);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Sascha, that worked perfectly. Much gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

So basically javascript file run only once so you need to add EventListener to listen when you submit the form and update salonOwner through it

```
<form id="nameForm" class="nameForm" action="#">

    <label id="nameLabel" for="nameInput">Enter Your Name:</label>
    
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" class="nameInput" required>
    
    <button id="next" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

```
let salonOwner = {
  name: ""
}

//Initilize Dom Element
let form = document.querySelector("#nameForm")


//Add EventListener to Update The salonOwner Object
form.addEventListener("submit" , (e)=>{
  let name = document.querySelector("#nameInput").value;
  salonOwner.name = name;
})
```

Comment: if you like to prevent the deafult of form just add e.preventDefault() in the eventListener body

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the JS running once.  I will definetly remember that in the future!